# simple applicaiton in asp.net where user enters amount in text box and clicks checkout with paypal

Tags: asp.net, paypal, payment-gateway

I need a simple PayPal integration in my asp.net website where user simply enters amount he wants to top up his account with and clicks on PayPal button which will take him to PayPal and will return me with success or failed message. I searched a lot and found really complex demos I want simple functionality like I mentioned above any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

[Use-of-the-PayPal-payment-system-in-ASP-NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19184/Use-of-the-PayPal-payment-system-in-ASP-NET)

Looks pretty simple.

Comment: Do not use this code - hidden variables are NOT secure.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply but i am not getting paypal transaction number in return when i follow this example. only success or fail message is coming in url